# Where to save state in an iPhone app

Tags: ios

I'm wondering the proper place to save the running state of an app now that iCloud and iOS5 have changed how the various options work.

NSUserDefaults? I always had the impression this was for settings. Is it okay for state as well?

The app's NSDocumentDirectory? Isn't that synced with iCloud? I have no particular desire to upload the state of the app. It's unnecessary.

Caches? That's now purged occassionally. It's not a secure spot to save things.

So what's the official, recommended place to save state these days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like iOS developers tend to use NSUserDefaults even though it's meant for user settings as you point out.

For example I recently added the popular Appirater library to my app and discovered that it uses NSUserDefaults to store its state (such as how many times the app was launched).